# How to identify if this is 20th run of my application?

Tags: android

If I put counter at `OnCreate()`, then it will count how many times activity was created, when I need to identify 20th run of the application.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - explain why you need to do this and it might help get a definitive answer.

Comment: @MisterSquonk, if user used my application 20 times (i.e. he needs this application), I would like to thank him (show message with 'thank you' one time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class. `MyApplication extends Application` and set it as your Application in the manifest.

```
<application 
  android:name="MyApplication" 
  . 
  . 
  .
```

In MyApplication you implement `onCreate` and `onTerminate`.

I took this from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/60140c9049add77b).

Once you have implemented your own create and terminate, in those methods you can increase the count and store it in `sharedpreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are asking for a way to store data between Application sessions. You could achieve this e.g. by using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). With those, it is extremely simple to read and write data that can be accessed at any time from your application.

Comment: I know about SharedPreferences. But my question is different: when I need to increase the counter? OnCreate() of Activity seems to be wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on what Martin said (which is correct) remember that every time the activity calls finish() then is navigated back to, it will increase that counter by 1.

But, if they say, just took a short trip to the home screen or took a call, and reopened your app while it was still in the background in OnStop(), it won't hit your OnCreate(), and goes straight to OnRestart()...

See the lifecycle here, and plan accordingly to where you want to put the increment logic.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html